# Deserialize JSON with GSON with variable child names

Tags: json, parsing

I'm attempting to deserialize json with GSON. I have tried to run the response in http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ but the variable field names in "data" are causing issues.

My question is

1. What should the main class look like?
2. And what should the "data" class look like? Taking into account that the nodes under data will be different for every call?
3. How will i read "data" into a list in android studio?

Here is the [json response](http://diskizone.com/wp-json/sportspress/v2/tables?filter[sp_season]=2017/2018&filter[sp_league]=psl&per_page=1&filter[orderby]=pos&order=asc)

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's say your JSON input is a String called jsonString and we have our data class called DataClass then your main should look something like this:

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   DataClass[] dataClassArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DataClass[].class);
   ```
2. The trick here is to have the "data" serialized as `Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>`. Your DataClass should look something like this:

   ```
   class DataClass {
       private Integer id;
       // ...
       // TODO: add the rest of your properties...
       // ...
       private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> data;

       public Integer getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public void setId(Integer id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       // ...            
       //TODO: add getters/setters for the rest of your properties...
       // ...

       public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> getData() {
           return data;
       }

       public void setData(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> data) {
           this.data = data;
       }
   }
   ```
3. See #1 (DataClass[].class). You can convert the array to a list if you really want.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you test this in a unit test. Copy/paste your json input to a string variable and run code from #1. You can put a breakpoint and see what gets parsed to dataClassArray.
For me it worked in a unit test.